# WindowsでのRuby実験環境構築パッケージについて

Tags: ruby, windows, ruby-on-rails

Ruby on Rails で書いたサーバソフトウエアのパッケージがあり、それを用いてチュートリアルをしようとしています。そのために、「Windowsで簡単な設定でRuby on Railsをdevelopment実行環境で動かす」ことが必要になっています。

対象者は、コマンドプロンプトでコマンド打ち込むぐらいは出来る人が、sshは知らないかもしれない、ぐらいのスキルのユーザを想定しています。

たとえば、インストーラで一通り開発環境を設定できるようなパッケージがあると思うのですが、WindowsでのRuby開発環境に疎いので、適切な解を見付けられていません。

教えてください。

蛇足ですが、最終的にはHerokuで実験できるようにすることも考えているのですが、恐らく、外のサービスでアカウント作るよりは、手元で動かす方がハードルが低いのではないかと考えています。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

その名も [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/) というものがあります。能書き:

- Ruby 2.0.0 または 2.1.5
- Rails 4.1
- Bundler
- Git
- Sqlite
- TinyTDS
- SQL Server サポート
- DevKit

インストールが完了すると、スタートメニューにメニュー項目が追加されており、rails コマンドにパスの通ったコマンドプロンプトを起動できる、という使用感のようです。(私は試したことがありません)

もう 1 つ [RailsFTW](http://railsftw.bryanbibat.net/) というのもあります。こちらは「やっつけ仕事だが、RailsInstallerに比べてインストール時にインターネット接続しなくてもokという利点がある」ということだそうです。同梱物:

- RubyInstaller 2.1.5 32bit
- Rails 4.1.8
- sqlite3 と mysql2 の gem
- SQLite3 DLL
- MariaDB の libmysql.dll

Comment: ついにrailsinstallerのruby2系のバージョンが出たんですね。ちょっと前みたときも 1.9.3のままだったきがしますが。

Comment: どうもありがとうございます。Heroku の設定手順書いてて、RailsInstallerあるのを見付けてます。見てみるつもりです。

Comment: 結局、ネットワークアクセスが充実してない人でも使える、という点と、パッケージングの点で、RailsInstaller が良いという結論に達して、手順書きました。ただ、残念なことに、CA証明書の設定だけはやらないとダメですね。この部分の情報がイマイチなので驚きました。。

Answer (score 8):

小さなツールや使用するgemの依存が少ないならほぼ問題無いのですが、使用するgemにC言語による拡張が含まれる場合は途端にハードルが高くなります。rubyinstaller である程度はビルド出来るのですが windows に対応していない gem も多数存在しますし、なかなかのいばらの道です。
予め大きい依存になる事が想定されるのであれば、vagrant 上で環境を構築し、もしコードの変更がある場合は vagrant の共有フォルダを windows 側から触って貰うのが良いかと思います。

Comment: おっしゃるとおり、たしかに、Gemが増えると問題が増えそうですね。一方、とりあえずの実験環境は、Railsのベースだけで試せるように限っているので、実験して大丈夫であれば、そのまま行けるのではないかと思います。

Answer (score 4):

http://rubyinstaller.org/

これとかいかがでしょう？

VirtualBoxとVagrantが使えるなら

[rails-dev-box - VagrantでRails開発環境を作るならこれ！ MOONGIFT](http://www.moongift.jp/2014/11/rails-dev-box-vagrant%E3%81%A7rails%E9%96%8B%E7%99%BA%E7%92%B0%E5%A2%83%E3%82%92%E4%BD%9C%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AA%E3%82%89%E3%81%93%E3%82%8C%EF%BC%81/)

もあります。こっちのがサーバ環境には近いので外部にホストした際の環境差異は小さいのではないかと。

Comment: ありがとうございます。Vagrant使うのも手かなとは思うのですが、コマンドプロンプトでの操作が多いので躊躇してました。他の提案も頂いているので、少し考えてみます。

Answer (score 3):

スキルセットを考慮すると

http://rubyinstaller.org

をつかってそのままWindowsで環境を構築するのが良さそうに思えます

Railsを動作させるのに必要なgemには、バージョンによってはNative extensionを使用するものもあると思うので、devkitもいれる必要があるかもしれません

同一のネットワークに接続できるのであれば↑のRuby環境を共有フォルダに構築して、それぞれの開発端末からはPATH変数などを設定するバッチファイルのみを配布するのありだと思います

Comment: ありがとうございます。devkit 入れないといけないようですが、逆にdevkit分けられてる点は好感持てます。少し詳しく見てみたいと思います。

Answer (score 3):

https://www.nitrous.io/ のように、オンライン上でコーディングして実行できる環境を使うとよいかもしれません。

Comment: そうでした。この手があった。類似のを見ていたのですがスッカリわすれていました。受講者を考えると日本語の方が良いので、ニフティクラウド C4SA 使うのが良さそうです。。今回はこの方向で試してみようかと思い始めました。

Answer (score 3):

まだ紹介されていないので紹介します。実開発では使用したことがありませんが、[Bitnami Ruby Stack](https://bitnami.com/stack/ruby) が使いやすそうです。(redmine stackで使用中)

以下のアプリケーションが同梱されています。
Ruby(2.0.0), Rails, RVM, MySQL, SQLite, NGINX, Apache, Memcache and Varnish, Git and Subersion, Sphinx, PHP and phpMyAdmin

Gem関係ではThin, RMagick, Rake, Mongrel, Passenger, Nokogiriが適用済みで、Msysも入っているのでネイティブビルドでも多少はカバーできそうです。

以下導入に当たっての注意点や検討事項

- railsアプリのサンプルコードが入ってるので参考になるかもしれません
- 上記プログラムが内包されているので、インターネットから隔離されている環境でも使えます。(gemを追加しない場合に限る)
- インストール時にMySQLやPostgreSQLはサービスとして起動されるので、既存のインスタンスがある場合は注意が必要です。(インストール時にカスタムを選択してください)
- railsなので大丈夫だとは思いますが、Windowsのファイルシステムであるが故、大文字小文字と改行文字には注意してください。
- gitやsubversionもインストール対象ですが、実運用では[TortoiseGit](https://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/),[TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html)等を導入されることを検討したほうがよいかもしれません
- 環境にサービスをインストールするので、バージョンアップを行う場合は注意が必要です

Comment: ありがとうございます。これも良さそうですね。今後紹介したいとおもいます。